# how can an additional natural join with the same table twice *reduce* the row count

Tags: postgresql

This is real results from my database. I spend some time trying to reproduce this behavior with an SSCCE but failed. How is the last of the below results possible?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rr.resource    a
--- 15771

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rr.resource    a
NATURAL JOIN rr.interface   b
--- 41419

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM rr.resource    a
NATURAL JOIN rr.interface   b
NATURAL JOIN rr.interface   c
--- 0
```

The zero (0) row count in the last query is consistent and repeatable every time.
In some examples I created, adding a second natural join with the same table twice yields the same number of rows (as I was expecting). How is then the above result possible?

Comment: What data types are the columns?

Comment: Also, what specific version are you using?

Comment: @Phil I didn't want to provide any more information that would have made the question too narrow and/or too specific for my case; the accepted answer does indeed show how this kind of behavior is possible and that's what I was asking.

Comment: not a problem. It's a good question. Nearly had us stumped for a second :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, `NULL` is causing this, because `NULL<>NULL`. One of the columns in your self-joined table will be all `NULL`s.

Here's a little test case that shows why this can happen. Naughty `NULL` equality and the way `NATURAL JOIN` works, picking column names to join on for you.

Setup:

```
create table one ( a integer, b integer );

CREATE TABLE two ( A INTEGER , c integer);

insert into one values (1,1);

insert into two values (1,1);

insert into two values (1,null);

insert into two values(2,NULL);
```

Queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ONE
NATURAL JOIN TWO tttt;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ONE
NATURAL JOIN TWO tttt
NATURAL JOIN TWO ttttt;
```

The first query will give 2, the second query 1.

Your problem will just be a more advanced version of this.

Use `JOIN .... USING` with the columns of your own choice to workaround this.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For the OP's query that results to 0, it means that all rows of table `rr.interface` (well, not all, actually the ones that survive the join to `rr.resource`) have at least one of their column values as `null`.